# How to fire on unhiding rows or columns

Tags: vba, excel, events, event-handling

Some users hide columns/rows and forget to unhide them before saving a workbook. I want to catch that with unhide all columns/rows on the save event with

```
Sub ReInvisible()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

this works fine but I would like to inform the user that all hidden columns/rows are now visible. Now I am looking for a way to trigger on unhiding a column/row so as soon as at least one column or row is made visible I want to fire a messagebox.

In `VB.NET` I would try to write my own `event` but in `VBA` I do not know how I can do a workaround. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you mean you want to raise an event when the user unhides a row/column, or when the code you posted actually unhides something?

Comment: When the code unhides something.

Comment: You can create custom events in VBA too, take a look a CPearson article about events : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Comment: Since unhiding initiated from your code, than it's easier just check the number of hidden rows and columns, and if any then unhide and show message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
Sub ReInvisible()
    Dim lVisColCount          As Long
    Dim lVisRowCount          As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
        lVisColCount = .Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
        lVisRowCount = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        If .Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count <> lVisColCount Then MsgBox "Columns unhidden"
        If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count <> lVisRowCount Then MsgBox "Rows unhidden"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. doese this code run on your maschine? I created a new WB and hid a column but I get an Overflow Error in lVisColCount = .Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Did you put any data in it?

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot!